# why TABLOCKX does not have deadlock

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help to understand why tablockx does have deadlock in multithreaded application.

I tried tablockx with SqlQueryStress will multiple threads still i am not getting any deadlock

Answer (score 2):

Because deadlocks can pretty much only occur when you use row-level locking.  The most basic example of a deadlock is:

- Transaction A is updating Rows 1,2,3
- Transaction B is updating Rows 3,2,1
- A modifies row 1, opens (locks) row 2, and waits for row 3
- B locks row 3, and waits for row 2

Since A has 2 and needs 3, and B has 3 and needs 2, they will wait forever unless the query engine catches it, which is what causes a deadlock.  Basically it's an infinite logical loop of waits that get cancelled.

When you use a `TABLOCK`, which indicates to the engine to use table locking instead of row locking, Transaction A would either wait for the whole table to be available if B already had it open, or would place a lock on the whole table if it were available, blocking any other transaction from modifying the table until it is complete.

Comment: when we tablockx it is right the sql server applies lock on the table but for example some another transaction tries to acquire tablockx  on the same resource then the  transaction have to wait but it should have some limit when the sql server  handles or throw exception that this resource has already acquire exclusive table lock ,result deadlock to another transaction

Comment: If you are using `TABLOCK` to avoid deadlocks in the first place, why would you want it throw a deadlock error if it takes too long on a wait?  Also that has nothing to do with the posted question.  If you have a feature request post it on Microsoft Connect.

Comment: Sorry you misunderstood , i don't what throw a deadlock error i just want know how long the another transaction  will wait as long as the priory transaction who acquire lock will release the lock.

Comment: It will wait until the first transaction is complete. There's no way to know how long that will be since the first transaction could be waiting on something else which is waiting on yet another process which is querying another linked server or something.  Can you tell me precisely what you are hoping to get?

Comment: I am using tablockx to get custom auto number using MAXID. Since it apply lock on the table i want to know what we will happend  if other process try to get the MAXID. Is tablockx will create any other issue other than holding the table until the transaction . IF we are using C# code to execute the sp may be it will give time out.

Comment: TablockX won't necessarily keep another process from reading the `maxid` - it'll depend on the isolation level of that other process.

Comment: But if both transactions were locking the same *two* (or more) tables (using `TABLOCK`), couldn't there be a situation similar to the one you are describing with `ROWLOCK`? That is, one transaction took hold of table A, the other grabbed table B, and both were then waiting for each other to release the other table.

Comment: @AndriyM - potentially but that's a lot less likely to happen.  I think queries issue table locks as soon as the query is executed, not rolling locks like happen with rows.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds plausible indeed. And I realise now that my question was somewhat irrelevant, because the original question does seem to be about a single table lock as opposed to multiple row locks.